# Why do I get a morphism $f_P: Spec \mathcal{O}_K \to \mathcal{X}$ for every point $P\in X(K)$? How does this morphism look like?

Tags: schemes

Hello,

my question probably isn't too hard, but I can't find the answer.

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{X} /\mathcal{O}_K$ be an arithmetic surface, which is a regular model for a projective, smooth curve $X/K$ and let $(\mathcal{L}, ||\cdot ||)$ be a hermitian line bundle on $X$. Then every point $P\in X(K)$ admits a homomorphism $f_P : Spec \mathcal{O}_K \to \mathcal{X}$.

This is what is said and I don't understand why $f_P$ must exist and what it does.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: This is nothing specifically to do with Arakelov theory, and you want $\mathcal{X}$ to be proper over $\mathcal{O}_K$.  That said, which part do you not understand?  Are you happy that a $K$-point of $X$ is the same as a morphism $\textbf{Spec }K \to X$, and an $\mathcal{O}_K$-point of $\mathcal{X}$ is the same as a morphism $\textbf{Spec }\mathcal{O}_K \to \mathcal{X}$?  If so, you just need to think about why, on a projective variety, having a $K$-point is the same as having an $\mathcal{O}_K$ point.  Then look up the valuative criterion of properness.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is probably everything I needed. Though I can't find where in the lecture notes that I am reading it is required that $\mathcal{X}$ should be proper over $\mathcal{O}_K$, but maybe I just missed that.

Comment: I deleted the tag "arakelov-theory".

Comment: As Martin said, this requires $\mathcal X$ to be projective. Anywayt, the adjective *projective* is probably implicit in the use of the word *model*, and hopefully included in its definition.